# Make local duplicate of local git repo

Tags: git, dropbox

I have a git repo on my local machine that I **need** to 100% duplicate locally.

The problem is that I've been keeping my local repos in dropbox which syncs up all my PCs. Today dropbox decided to finally mess with the repo (it's about time) and so I quickly disconnected my net and booted up my other PC - this repo is fine!

Obviously, being the unexperienced git user that I am - I haven't pushed in **a long time** and so there's a lot of work resting on this other machine. I need to make a duplicate of this repo outside of dropbox so that I can save my work and branches, and push up to a remote where it will be nice and safe.

I've tried git clone with a few different parameters but I've only managed to clone a single branch. I had a look at the mirror command but can't figure it out. Any help!?

Comment: Just copy the entire directory.

Comment: @SLaks will this work? I tried this and it said it's not a git repository.

Comment: Does the original directory have a `.git` subfolder?

Comment: @SLaks Yeah it does, although I just showed hidden folders. Maybe it didn't copy?

Comment: @SLaks Whew, that worked. Thanks dude, was worried I'd lost some stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by user SLaks: "Just copy the entire directory."

Answer (score 2):

You may want `git clone --mirror`. From the [git-clone man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html):

```
   --mirror
       Set up a mirror of the source repository. This implies --bare. Compared to --bare, --mirror not
       only maps local branches of the source to local branches of the target, it maps all refs
       (including remote-tracking branches, notes etc.) and sets up a refspec configuration such that
       all these refs are overwritten by a git remote update in the target repository.
```

Copying the directory will work, also; however, you must ensure that your copy includes hidden files and folders, also. (i.e.: instead of `cd my-git-repo; cp * ../my-clone`, invoke `cp -R my-git-repo my-clone`). This will copy your work-tree as well, which is fine for simple backups, but not desirable if you plan to clone from this copy.